# Focus window in background in AutoIt (MouseClick)

Tags: loops, click, window, focus, autoit

I'd like to download GTA V for PC. The download is extremely slow (40kb/s), but when you click pause and then start it again downloads with 5,5mb/s for 1 minute.

I want to write a script for it in **AutoIt**.

But how i can focus the window AND work on in the foreground.

The window info of the download manager (mouse pointed at the button)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry5dq.png

My script looks like this at the moment:

```
While 1

; Here, the focus has to go, right?

MouseClick ( "primary" [, 637, 460 [, clicks = 1 [, speed = 0]]] )
Sleep(1000)
MouseClick ( "primary" [, 637, 460 [, clicks = 1 [, speed = 0]]] )

Sleep(60000)
WEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that you got right coords from Autoit Window Info [screenshot](http://clip2net.com/s/3geSxLn)

Try to use WinActivate() and ControlClick() (in that choice the mouse is not used) :

```
  Opt("MouseCoordMode",2)     
  While 1
   $hwnd = WinActivate('Launcher')
   MouseClick ( "primary",637 ,460) ; with mouse coords
   Sleep(1000)
   ControlClick ( $hwnd, "", "[CLASS:AfxWnd110su; INSTANCE:2]") ;... and without mouse
   Sleep(60000)
   WinSetState ( $hwnd, "", @SW_MINIMIZE ); Minimaze the Launcher
  WEnd
```